# Align a box vertically with a text

Tags: vertical-alignment, wrap, report, box

I want to align the text and the box as follows : 
[image]

Thank's for your help !

Comment: You could use the `wrapfig` package, possibly in connection with `tcolorbox`. But it is not very helpful to post just screenshots.

Comment: Because i don't have any idea , what are you need for doing this ?

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tcbset{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black}
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[10]{r}[10pt]{6cm}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=0.9\linewidth,title=Why one should not just upload a
screenshot?]
Solutions may depend on the packages you're using, the document class etc. So it
is to your own benefit to provide some MWE.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]